# SQL SELF-JOIN with Oracle 11G - Finding a patient who has the same telephone number

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, self-join

I am stuck at a certain point with my select queries. I need to find from the table 'patient' a cellphone number that has a matching pair with the other patients cellphone number (if that makes any sense).

at the moment I got this insert values from the table patient:

```
insert into patient
values(1022010201, 88.2, 77, 0676762516);
insert into patient
values(1022010202, 66.7, 55, 0676762518);
insert into patient
values(1022010203, 59.6, 65, 0676762517);
insert into patient
values(1022010204, 99.1, 76, 0676762515);
insert into patient
values(1022010205, 88.2, 89, 0676762514);
insert into patient
values(1022010207, 91.4, 76, 0676762513);
insert into patient
values(182704726, 54.4, 44, 0676762516);
```

the first and the last telephone numbers are the same. With my 'self-join' query I am not getting that one value, but I am also getting the other values.

In a way it makes sense, because my query connects the table patient with it self. So in this way the select query does find numbers who are a matching pair.

So at this point I am stuck how to only get the real matching phone numbers instead of all the others.

```
this is my select query at the moment:
select p1.telefoonnr, p2.telefoonnr
from patient p1, patient p2
where p1.telefoonnr = p2.telefoonnr;
```

this is the result:

```
TELEFOONNR           TELEFOONNR         
-------------------- --------------------
676762516            676762516            
676762518            676762518            
676762517            676762517            
676762515            676762515            
676762514            676762514            
676762513            676762513            
06-12345678          06-12345678          

 7 rows selected
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the awnser to my own question.

The result that I was looking for is this:

```
TELEFOONNR                  BSN
-------------------- ----------
676762516            1022010201 
676762516             182704726
```

This was possible due the following query:

```
select telefoonnr, bsn
from patient
where telefoonnr =
(select telefoonnr 
from patient 
group by telefoonnr
having count(*) >1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select telefoonnr,count(telefoonnr)
from patient 
group by telefoonnr
having count (telefoonnr) > 1;
```

This is like finding duplicates in your table. So the above query will give you the `telefoonnr` along with `count` and other details from your table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The '*' does nothing for me. It will display an error message 'missing expression'.

Comment: @MaximedeLange:- Remove the `*`. And see if that gives the result you want. Instead of `*` you can name the columns which you want.

Comment: That's strange. I have tried multiple things yesterday. Not only your solution but also different ones on the web. They all resulted in giving all the rows or giving 0 rows. Could there be a problem with my insert values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the patients who share a cell number *and* the number they share, then the self-join gets you there:

```
Select  p1.ID, p2.ID, p1.telefoonnr
from    Patient  p1
join    Patient  p2
    on  p2.telefoonnr = p1.telefoonnr
    and p2.ID <> p1.ID;
```